# Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to determine the value of $x$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following modular arithmetic question using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, using this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3L79qw2S14). (We learned a different method in our class, but I found this easier to grasp).
$$x \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ 5)$$
$$x \equiv 2 (\text{mod} \ 7)$$
$$x \equiv 3 (\text{mod} \ 9)$$
$$x \equiv 4 (\text{mod} \ 11)$$

I then represented $x$ as a sum of $4$ boxes, such that the first term is "related" to $\text{mod} \ 5$ (i.e. the $1^{st}$ term will not be made $0$ due to the $\text{mod} \ 5$), the second term is related to $\text{mod} \ 7$ and so on. Here's what I mean by "related":

> If we only consider $\text{mod} \ 5$, the value of box $1$ is $693$, the value of box $2$ is $495$, then $693 \  \text{mod} \ 5 = 3$ but $495 \  \text{mod} \ 5 = 0$. Likewise, if we only consider $\text{mod} \ 7$, then the value of box $1$ is $693 \  \text{mod} \ 7 = 0$ but $495 \  \text{mod} \ 7=5$. And so on...

After doing all that, I have $$x = (7 \times 9 \times 11) + (5 \times 9 \times 11) + (5 \times 7 \times 11) + (5 \times 7 \times 9)$$

The next step is applying the $\text{mod} \ 5$ to $x$:
$$\begin{align}
x \ \text{mod} \ 3 &\equiv 691 \ \text{mod} \ 5 + 495 \ \text{mod} \ 5 + 385 \ \text{mod} \ 5 + 315 \  \text{mod} \ 5 \\ &\equiv 693 \ \text{mod} \ 5 + 0 + 0 + 0 \\ &\equiv 693 \ \text{mod} \ 5 \\ &\equiv 3 \ (\text{mod} \ 5)
\end{align}$$

This is where I get stuck. In the video, and the video doesn't explain how to deal with such a scenario.

PS - If there is a more "intuitive" or more efficient version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I'd be grateful if you could share it.

PPS - Sorry if the question is a bit awkwardly formulated. As you can guess this is my first doing this.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation ?

Comment: Some formatting tips.  Look at how at how I aligned the calculations.  You don't have to worry about putting spaces in expressions; MathJax will take care of that.  There are two operators for modulus: `$x\pmod{17}$` gives  $x\pmod{17}$ and `$x\mod{17}$` gives $x\mod{17}$  Of course, if you don't like the spacing, you will have to do what you did with \text or use \operatorname.

Comment: Why on earth should $x = (7 \times 9 \times 11) + (5 \times 9 \times 11) + (5 \times 7 \times 11) + (5 \times 7 \times 9)$?  If $x=17$ and  $x\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod 5$, we don't have $17=x = 3*5 + 2*5 + 2*3=31$.

Comment: Why are you doing mod 3 instead of mod 9.?  $3$ is not one of your components.

Comment: "the video doesn't explain how to deal with such a scenario. "  You get that the "experimental" $x\equiv 3\pmod 5$ but the "real" $x \equiv 1\pmod 5$.  So you need to multiply $3\pmod 5$ by $?$ to get $1\pmod 5$.  So $3*2 \equiv 1\pmod 5$ you will get the "real" $x$ is $2*(7\cdot 9\cdot 11) + ......$  The video explained that in the second mod they tested but I *oppose* the idea of setting $x=7*9*11+5*9*11+ 5*7*11+5*7*9$.  $x$ *ISN"T* equal to that.  $x = a*695+b*495+c*385+d*315$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a *TERRIBLE* video.  But the technique is interesting.

SO we have

$x = a*693 + b*495 + c*385+d*315$.

First we do $\mod 5$.

$x \equiv 3*a + 0 +0 +0\equiv 3a \pmod 5$ and we need $3a \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.  Now trial and error shows us that $3*2 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ so $a=2$ will do.

Now $\mod 7$

$x\equiv 0 + b*5 + 0  + 0\equiv 5b \pmod 7$.  So we need $5b\equiv 2\pmod 7$.

He doesn't explain how do do this.  Trial and error shows us that $5*6 =30\equiv 2 \pmod 2$ so $b=6$ will do.

Then we $\mod 9$ (not $3$)

$x \equiv 7c \pmod 9$ and we need $7c \equiv 3\pmod 9$.

Okay.   No trial and error any more.... $7c = 3 + 9k$ so $7\frac c3= 1+ 3k$ so $3|c$.  Le $c = 3e$.  $7e = 1+3k$ so $(2*3+1)e= 1+3k$ so $e = 1 + 3(k-2)$ so we can have $e=1$ and $c = 3$.   $7*c = 21 =3+18 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$.

So $c= 3$ will do.

And finally $\mod 11$ we have $x \equiv 315d\equiv 7d\pmod {11}$ so we need $7d\equiv 4\pmod 11$.

$7d = 4 + 11k$

$(11-4)d= 4 + 11k$

$-4d = 4 + 11(k+d)$ so $d=-1$ will do.

So we can have $x = 2*693 + 6*495+ 3*385 - 315=5196$

Of course that not the smallest positive answer.

To get a reasonable answer I'd alternate a few negative and positive values.

Instead of $b=6$ we can have $b\equiv 6 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$ and use $b=-1$ to get

$x = 2*693 -495 + 3*385 -315=1731$ will do. (And if my instincts are right that is smallest value between $0$ and $5\times 7\times 9\times 11 = 3465$

$2*693 -495 + 3*385 -315\equiv 2*3 + 0 + 0 + 0 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

And $2*693 -495 + 3*385 -315\equiv 0-5 + 0 + 0 \equiv 2\pmod 7$.

And $2*693 -495 + 3*385 -315\equiv 0+0+3*7 +0+0\equiv 21 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$

And $2*693 -495 + 3*385 -315 \equiv 0+0+0-7\equiv 4 \pmod {11}$.

.....

I've never seen this method before.... but I ... sort of liked it.  But the presentation in that video was *terrible*.

Comment: To determine the smallest positive value for $x$, can't you simply do $5196 \mod 3465=1731$?

Comment: Yeah but I'd rather get a smaller answer from the begining.  If we have $a693 + b*495+c*385 + d*315$ and $a,b,c,d$ are all positive I'm probably going to get a very large number.  To keep in in bound It make sense to choose $a*693 - (7-b)495 + c*385-(11-d)*315$.  That'll probably make the arithmetic a *lot* easier anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There should be $x = (7 \times 9 \times 11)\cdot(7 \times 9 \times 11)^{-1}_5\cdot 1 $ ${}+ (5 \times 9 \times 11)\cdot(5 \times 9 \times 11)^{-1}_7\cdot 2 $ ${}+ (5 \times 7 \times 11)\cdot(5 \times 7 \times 11)^{-1}_9\cdot 3 $ ${}+ (5 \times 7 \times 9)\cdot (5 \times 7 \times 9)^{-1}_{11}\cdot 4$ for this approach.

Comment: Hmm, it is a bit troubling to see inverse $\mod 9$ since it is not necessarily true for non–primes

Comment: There's a version of CRT that has as a pre-condition that all modules considered have to be mutually coprime. Hence the inverse exists. Anyway as $gcd(m_i,m_j)=1$ one may use extended euclidean algorithm to compute $am_i+bm_j=1$ so $b$ will be such inverse of $m_j$ (i.e. $m_j^{-1}$) $\pmod{m_i}$. Then we multiply them up.

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad.

Comment: You need to solve $\omega \times 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$.  There is no inverse mod $9$ that work for all values but as  $5\cdot 7\cdot 11$ is coprime to $9$ (That's the entire *point*) then there is an inverse for $5*7*11$ which would be the inverse for $(-4)(-2)2\equiv 16\equiv 7$ which is...counts on fingers $7,14,21,28$.... $4$.  So $(3*4)*5*7*11 \equiv 3\pmod 9$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for me to solve a CRT problem is like this:
$$x \equiv1 \pmod{5} \implies x \in \{1,6,11,16,21,26\dots\}$$
$$x \equiv4 \pmod{11} \implies x \in \{4,15,26,\dots\}$$

Now one can immediately see the intersection at $x=26$, and indeed $x \equiv 26 \pmod{55}$ satisfies both $x \equiv1 \pmod{5}$ and $4 \pmod{11}$.

Similarly,
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod{7} \implies x \in \{2,9,16,23,30,\dots\}$$
$$x \equiv 3 \pmod{9} \implies x \in \{3,12,21,30,\dots\}$$
So $x \equiv 30 \pmod{63}$

Now, from there I can solve it with the casual method:
$$x \equiv26 \pmod{55} \implies x=55k+26$$
$$\implies55k+26 \equiv30 \pmod{63} \implies 55k \equiv4 \equiv 130 \pmod{63}$$
$$\implies 11k \equiv 26 \equiv 341 \pmod{63} \implies k \equiv 31 \pmod{63} \implies k=63j+31$$
$$\implies x=55(63j+31)+26=3465j+1731 \implies x \equiv 1731 \pmod{3465}$$
Noting, of course, that $3465=5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11$

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do the Chinese Remainder Theorem is to do it one at a time, and merge two conditions repeatedly.

For two values, the best way to compute is given in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation), under the "Case of two moduli" section.

From here, you want to contract conditions: you can convert $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5, \; x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ into $x \equiv 16 \pmod {35}$ using this technique, and then repeat on $35$ and $9$ to find a condition for $x$ modulo $315$, and finally finish using the modulo $315$ condition and the modulo $11$ condition.

Comment: "best" is pretty subjective.  I rather think the technique described in the OP works pretty well.